# How can i access the value of the moving slider in a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

html

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<div class="slider" data-max="10"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<div class="slider" data-max="100"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
```

jquery

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
$(this).slider({
    value : 1,
    min   : 1,
    max   : $(this).data('max'),
    step  : 1,
    slide : function (event, ui) {
       var a= $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
    }
  });
 });
```

I want the value of the moving slider in a jquery variable
http://jsfiddle.net/s7uxtbu7/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  If you want to assign the value of the slider to a variable in JavaScript at the same time as you apply the value to the html element you can do something like this:

```
var a = 0;
$(".slider").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        value : 1,
        min   : 1,
        max   : $(this).data('max'),
        step  : 1,
        slide : function (event, ui) {
           a = ui.value;
           $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
setInterval(function(){
    alert(a);
},3000);
```

In your example you are initializing `a` within the slide function so it was not available outside of the function.  Also you were assigning the `a` variable to a jQuery setter which returns the dom element instead of a value.  In order to get the value you need to do something like

`a = $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value).html();`

Which is one of many alternatives to:

```
a = ui.value;
$(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
```

As given in the first example above.